# CSS questions events with hover

Tags: html, css

How do I change the CSS of an element that is nested while another is react to a event without javascript?
I have a menu which hides text while not in use, but when the user hovers on the edge, the menus is suppose to come up and show the text again. How do I get the element that is nested.

```
/*The div element that is being hovered over*/
#menu:hover
{
   /*how do i change the another div display*/
}
#text{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your div is nested in the menu its as simple as adding it to the rule:

```
#menu:hover div.nested-div
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU, I couldn't remember what the word was and its nested, thank you but can i just change div to the id of the element?